# File Copy from local to remote system using java IO

Tags: java, file, io, copy

I need to copy a file from my local system to remote system, for this I'm using the following code:

```
    public class Autohost {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Jainesh_Trivedi\\Desktop\\WAR\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war"));

        File f = new File("10.87.74.191\\C$\\IVS_Code\\tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\\webapps\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");
        f.createNewFile();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);



        }
        in.close();
        out.close();


    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.autohost2.java.Autohost.main(Autohost.java:18)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filename on this line

```
File f = new File("10.87.74.191\\C$\\IVS_Code\\tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\\webapps\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");
```

is not a valid UNC path. You need two backslashes (four, in code) to signal a remote path. Fixed version:

```
File f = new File("\\\\10.87.74.191\\C$\\IVS_Code\\tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\\webapps\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");
```

Also make sure that security settings on the remote machine are configured to allow your account the appropriate access.

Comment: Thank you the issue is resolved but I'm getting Access denied exception though the folder in which I'm copying has the permission to write in the folder @Ben N

Comment: @jainesh Right, machines don't just let anybody come in and write anywhere on them. You'll need to do some research and configure appropriate security settings.

Comment: Have already set the security settings to allow write on the folder @Ben N

Comment: Hi, could you please publish your code on how you set security/credentials settings to access the VM.

Comment: @GauravKhandelwal You need to do it manually with the standard Windows security ACL editor. (If the remote machine doesn't allow remote writes, it's almost certainly configured to disallow permission changes too.)